# unable to read data from the transport connection. the connection was closed facebook csharp sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I had developed a windows application to upload photos to the facebook by facebook c# sdk 5.4, but sometimes it give me the following error:

"unable to read data from the transport connection. the connection was closed"

anyone have idea on how to fix this? thanks

the function i use was to post my data

```
_fb.PostAsync(album_path, photoDetails);
```

and this for post complete

```
  public void fb_PostCompleted(object sender, FacebookApiEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Upload cancelled");
        }
        else if (e.Error == null)
        {
            // upload successful.
            this.lastUpload = false;
            updateCompleteCnt();
            //MessageBox.Show(e.GetResultData().ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // upload failed
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }

        this.progressbar_upload.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                this.progressbar_upload.Value = 0;
            }));
    }
```